# CSS Form Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble pushing down, margin and top do not seem to work. and aligning my form.  I would like the form (label -> input box) to be below the login text which is the background.

I currently have:

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="column-right-login">
          <form action="http://www.domain.co.nz/login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="homeLogin">
             <label for="email">Email Address: </label><input type="text" name="email" value="" />
             <label for="password">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" value="" />
              <br />
              <a href="http://www.domain.co.nz/forgot-password">Forgotten Password</a><br />
              <br />
              <a onclick="$('#login').submit();" class="button"><span>Login</span></a>
          </form>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('#login input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#login').submit();
        }
    });
    //--></script>   

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .column-right-login{
    background:url('../image/login.png') no-repeat;
    width:335px;
    height:154px;
}
```

Example:

[image]

**Update:**

I now have the code below but I cannot get my form to align:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column-right-login">
          <form action="http://www.domain.co.nz/login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="homeLogin">
             <label for="email">Email Address: </label><input type="text" name="email" value="" />
             <label for="password">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" value="" />
              <a href="http://www.domain.co.nz/forgot-password">Forgotten Password</a>
              <a onclick="$('#login').submit();" class="button"><span>Login</span></a>
          </form>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('#login input').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#login').submit();
        }
    });
    //--></script>   

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.column-right-login{
    background:url('../image/login.png') no-repeat;
    width:335px;
    height:154px;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 10px; /* top right bottom left */
}
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Once you get this working, I would suggest that you post the working code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com for advice on improving the code quality.

Comment: @Matt I agree,  it was the given code within opencart

Comment: Oh dear me, example code of that quality `<shakes head/>`

Comment: Won't a `<br />` before the password label just do the trick?

Comment: it was worse using <b> instead of label,  I am slowly improving

Comment: @Johnny5 I have removed them will update, crap code

Comment: @Jess you can consider using my solution (I have updated post). Just wrap label + input pair into divs and use margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use padding:

```
.column-right-login{
 background:url('../image/login.png') no-repeat;
 width:335px;
 height:154px;
 padding: 80px 0px 0px 50px; /* top right bottom left */
 }
```

Please be aware that padding adds to height/width, so you will have to adjust them (abstract from current value number of px you use for padding, for example in my example width = 335 - 50 and height = 154 - 80)

If you want to use margin on form and it is not working, just add

```
  display: block;
```

to the css for the form. I do not remember whether it is default or not - 4AM :)

UPDATE:

to put your inputs where you want, I would suggest wrapping label and input into divs. Then you can adjust position by using margin.

```
   <div style="margin-left: 40px;"><label1 ...><input ...></div>
   <div><label2 ...><input ...></div>
```

of course put styles to CSS :) hope this will work for you.

Comment: @mmk,  Thanks that worked fine,  I was trying to pad the form instead of the box when I was playing around,  Can you help with the form alignment?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell but it looks like your `background-image` needs to be positioned.

Try adding something like this to your css:

```
.column-right-login{
    background:url('../image/login.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 20%;  //HERE
    width:335px;
    height:154px;
}
```

This keeps the image to the left -- the first 0% -- and bumps it down 20%.

Obviously, you can adjust the numbers.